# Dynamic local images in Expo?

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, expo

I’m attempting to use a local image path from a JSON file, as recommended in previous posts, but this isn’t rendering.

I have tested the image link with a static reference and this working, so the image path is correct. However, referencing the path from the JSON file results in an error.

I’ve created a gist with my code snippet and the error log:

https://gist.github.com/SKempin/ec0ce4be2c0ef6633dc4b7ee06378ec4

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: This method is good and RN can use this kind of stuff

Answer (score 0):

I found this way in ES6 with back slash ${``}

```js
const Level_2_8 = () => {
const t = `./wait.png`
        switch (level) {
            case 61: return ( < Image source={require(`${t}`)} style={{ width: 50, height: 60 }} />)
                break;
            case 62: return (< Image source={require(`${t}`)} style={{ width: 50, height: 60 }} />)
                break;
            default: (< Image source={require(`${t}`)} style={{ width: 50, height: 60 }} />)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure `"card": "require('../assets/images/icon.png')"` is working, you should try without the quotes around require:

```
<Image
  source={require(marker.images.card)}
```

And:

```
"card": "../assets/images/icon.png"
```

Comment: That throws an error as removing the quotes stops it from being a string. Also the console log in the original code shows the quotes aren't being parsed.

Comment: what is happening if you only put the path in the json and the require in the image component? This should work, i don't think the require is executed by RN when it's part of a string. Edited answer

Comment: This also results in the same error. I have tried multiple attempts and variations of doing this, it seems that a path from a JSON file is simple not supported?

The only methods I have seen work are those where a variable is declared in a conditional statement, in the file itself: [See this example](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10216228233395827&set=p.10216228233395827&type=3&theater&ifg=1)

Comment: The solution was to covert the JSON file to a standard `.js` file, add `export const` prior to the variable name and remove the quotations around the `require` statement. Also remove the quotations around the keys.
    

https://gist.github.com/SKempin/ec0ce4be2c0ef6633dc4b7ee06378ec4#file-data-js

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing in my apps. But i thought you needed it in .json so I didn't mentioned it. Sorry for that, good luck with your app.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm wondering if I am attempting the structure of my app correctly however. I require offline images. Should I load these from a network and cache them, or should they all be bundled in my app and stored locally (my current approach)? I have around 30 images of 150kb.

Comment: Stored locally is ok, you should precache them tho, if you use expo, go to their doc, they explain quite easely how to do it. Else, you could use this link: https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image/issues/160#issuecomment-373938649

Comment: Thanks. Any tips of storing them on the network and then caching in Expo?